# Cut a substring in bash

Tags: bash, substring

Suppose I have the following string:

```
some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters
```

I need to extract this substring supposing that `foo/` and `/goo` are constant strings that are known in advance. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed one-liner does it.

```
sed 's#.*foo/##;s#/goo/.*##' file
```

Except for sed, awk, grep can do the job too. Or with zsh:

```
kent$  v="some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters"  

kent$  echo ${${v##*foo/}%%/goo/*}                                
substring
```

#### Note that:

comment by @Nahuel Fouilleul

> in ${var%%/goo/*} var must be a variable name, and can't be the result of expansion

The line should be divided into two statements, if work with bash.

```
$ echo $0
bash
$ v="some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters"
$ v=${v##*foo/}
$ v=${v%%/goo/*}
$ echo $v
substring
```

The line I executed in zsh, worked, but just I tested in bash, it didn't work.

```
$  echo $0
-zsh
$  v="some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters" 
$  echo ${${v##*foo/}%%/goo/*}                                
substring
```

Comment: in `${var%%/goo/*}` `var` must be a variable name, and can't be the result of expansion

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul thx, I put your comment in the answer. I just did the test in zsh, and it worked. my fault.

Comment: Could you give the two statements please

Comment: The first solution should probably read "or with *zsh*" then, no?

Comment: @Kent What if I have two lines how the sed solutions changes? i.e line1 /n                   some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters

Comment: @Yakov  it would be another problem. btw, you may want to check the `N`  command in sed man page.

Answer (score 2):

With variable expansion

```
line='some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters'
line=${line%%/goo*}             # remove suffix  /goo*
line=${line##*foo/}             # remove prefix  *ffo/
echo "$line"
```

or bash regular expression

```
line='some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters'
if [[ $line =~ foo/([^/]*)/goo ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know there are no other `/` in your "other letters", you can use `cut` :

```
 > echo "some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters" | cut -d'/' -f2
```

Comment: actually there is

Comment: Or `$ echo "some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters" | awk -F/ '{ print $2}'` )) But your option is better.

Comment: even if "other letters" don't have `/`, it will fail if "substring" contains `/`

Comment: All true - I was simply sharing an easy solution that only works in some specific cases - that is, when nothing else uses `/`.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of readability I think awk is a good solution

```
echo "some letters foo/substring/goo/some additional letters" | awk -v FS="(foo/|/goo)" '{print $2}'
```